# PHP Class Parameters used twice

Tags: php, oop

I am new to OOP, and I am switching all of my websites code to it! I am currently writing a class that grabs a user's information, and will eventually update it.

The code I am using is below:

```
<?php

    require("C:\wamp\www\postin'\db_connection.php");
    session_start();

    class user {

        public function __construct($userid, $connection, $information) {
            $this->userid = $userid;
            $this->connection = $connection;
            $this->information = $information;
        }   

        public function user_information($userid, $connection, $information) {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
            $params = array(':id' => $userid);
            try{
                $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute($params);
            }                               
            catch(PDOException $ex){
                echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
            }                       
            $columns = $stmt->fetch();
            return $columns["$information"];
        }

    }

    $username = new user($_SESSION["logged_in"], $connection, "username");
    echo $username->user_information($_SESSION["logged_in"], $connection, "username");
?>
```

Now as you can see on the last two lines of code (one from the end) I have to use the parameters twice. Basically the first parameter says what the ID is, second says what the `$connection` is, and the third is what I want to grab from the database. So what am I doing wrong? Did I define something I did not need to?

**EDIT**

Would the following be valid as well?

```
<?php

require("C:\wamp\www\postin'\db_connection.php");
session_start();

class user {

    public function user_information($userid, $connection, $information) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
        $params = array(':id' => $userid);
        try{
            $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($params);
        }                               
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
        }                       
        $columns = $stmt->fetch();
        return $columns["$information"];
    }

}

$username = new user();
echo $username->user_information($_SESSION["logged_in"], $connection, "username");
?>
```

Like is this in-properer, or wrong...?

Comment: Your edit version will be "valid" as well, but breaks with the idea of the point of having a class. Suppose you want to update, create, delete, or have other selections you make from users, then you will need the connection to your database in all of them. Well, the connection is something you can set in the construct and use it in every method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `user` class has all the information it needs as data members, then `user_information` doesn't need to take any arguments:

```
public function user_information() {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id";
    $params = array(':id' => $this->userid);
    try{
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($params);
    }                               
    catch(PDOException $ex){
        echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }                       
    $columns = $stmt->fetch();
    return $columns[$this->information];
}
```

Comment: @michaeljones it's technically right, but, IMHO, it misses the point - now the `user` class holds no data, so why would you even have it? With this design you can't pass a user between different parts of the application, but are forced to pass the variables independently.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a lot of questions about the way a class works and about OOP I will try to give you a little direction.
There is no standard way of building your class. You are the one that decides what goes where in terms of what belongs to the class and what needs to be injected. This is just to tell you that you cannot pin yourself down. You need to get a feel for it and build a logic.
I took your class and rebuild it some with added comments. Hope that will help you some. Good luck!

```
    <?php

require ("C:\wamp\www\postin'\db_connection.php");
session_start();

class user {

    public $dbconnection;

    public function __construct($connection) {
        /**
         * Your user class interacts with the database.
         * Inject the connection here and set your
         * global class variable.
         */
        $this -> dbconnection = $connection;
    }

    public function user_information($userid, $column) {
        /**
         * The userid and column are specific for this
         * method action. No need to set these variables
         * in the global scope of the class.
         */

        $query = "SELECT" . $column . " FROM users WHERE id = :id";

        $params = array(':id' => $userid);
        try {
            $stmt = $this -> dbconnection -> prepare($query);
            $stmt -> execute($params);
        } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            echo("Failed to run query: " . $ex -> getMessage());
        }
        $result = $stmt -> fetch();

        return $result;
    }

}

$username = new user($connection);
echo $username -> user_information($_SESSION["logged_in"], $information);
?>
```

Comment: Would I still have to do this: $username = new user($_SESSION["logged_in"], $connection, "username");? Then also what is the point of the __constructor?

Comment: The constructor is meant to create your basic object. Basically you decide what your basic object looks like. Just image you have a class for a dog. The basic features go in the constructor, like four paws, tail, barking and fur. In your methods you decide the color of the fur, how loud it is barking, and things like that.

Comment: No, you don't put the extra arguments in your method. I made an error and will adjust the answer.